# How to import samples to Korg iElectribe app for iOS

Tags: software, drums, samples

As far as I can tell from some youtube videos, it is possible to use different drum samples in the [iOS iElectribe app by KORG](http://www.korguser.net/ielectribe/en/follow.html), but I can't figure out how or find any documentation on this.  Does someone know how this is done?

Comment: You should post this question to Korg's Apple iPad app user forums, located at this link. http://www.korgforums.com/forum/phpBB2/viewforum.php?f=58

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to import samples into the iElectribe app but you can import samples with the Electribe Wave.